# shared preferences causes build to fail flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

i have no problem compiling a project but when i add shared prefrencess i get this error which i cant quit understand what should i do . the links give me 404 my gradle is 6.7 which is above 3.4.0

```
AILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':shared_preferences_android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':shared_preferences_android:classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :shared_preferences_android
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':shared_preferences_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':shared_preferences_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

> shared_preferences: ^2.0.13

Edit : i just found that my pub get dose not work when i add shared preferences , every time i do pub get i get this error:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in spnow... 
Insufficient permissions to the resource in pub.dartlang.org package repository.
You can modify credential using: pub token add pub.dartlang.org pub get failed (65; pub token add pub.dartlang.org) Process finished with exit code 65
```

what is this

Comment: try upgrading Gradle and the Gradle build plugin

Comment: @eeqk Ok i just found that my pub get dose not work when i add shared prefrences , every time i do pub get i get this error: gradle dose not seems to be the problem .

Running "flutter pub get" in spnow...                           
Insufficient permissions to the resource in https://pub.dartlang.org package repository. You can modify credential using:
    pub token add https://pub.dartlang.org
pub get failed (65;     pub token add https://pub.dartlang.org)
Process finished with exit code 65

what is this ?